# Is it OK to add a tag that should be a synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, edits, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Problem is: there is a [ble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ble) and a [bluetooth-lowenergy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-lowenergy) tag. They refer to exactly the same thing, but for some reason they're still not synonyms. Apparently no one with enough reputation has started a synonym request. There is one question here on Meta that addresses this issue, but over a month later, and nothing has happened.

So, is it OK to add the `ble` tag, if the questioner only used `bluetooth-lowenergy` and the other way around? The `ble` tag gets less attention, apparently, and many people that ask questions with it would probably get better results if they used both tags.

Comment: To put it more specific, you're asking if you should make it so both tags exist on a question. You already know the answer, you're just looking for the right words to say no.

Comment: @Gimby, did you mean to say "...words to say so"? I honestly don't get what you're saying with that comment.

Comment: Yeah, that happens :/ Sometimes I take too much creative freedom on meta when expressing myself. I meant to say "the answer is **no** and you already know it, now lets figure out the reason why not". I've been giving it some thought, and if I would see your edit in review I would reject it as "no improvement whatsoever". But that's me, lets see if other people agree.

Comment: I'd say making sure the question is found by people looking for the topic is an improvement.

Comment: No, it’s not OK. See also [Mass-edits adding tag-synonym candidate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330052)