# Mass-edits adding tag-synonym candidate

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-synonym-process, bulk-tagging

During edit-reviewing I noticed that currently a user is mass-editing posts tagged [bluetooth-lowenergy] by adding the [ble]-tag which is proposed as a synonym but not yet accepted.

Does double-tagging the posts make sense as the tags are not synonyms yet? Should those edits be approved or rejected?

Comment: @yellowantphil Ah, thanks, I haven't seen this post as it is dorwned in all the documentation noise and I only searched for topics concerning the general case, not for this specific instance.

Comment: I've asked in SOCVR to help in reviewing the last pending edits

Comment: I VTC because the other question is marked [status-completed]

Comment: @piet.t May I recommend [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aq%20closed%3ano%20-%5bdocumentation*%5d%20-%5bjobs*%5d) as your Meta "home page"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this serves absolutely no purpose. Once the [synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330042) is approved, the tags will be merged anyway. Furthermore, the user forgets to improve other aspects of posts, like [removing (misspelled) 'thanks'](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13161193). If you improve a post, you should improve everything you can, [not just adding a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251261/ok-to-approve-edits-that-only-add-remove-tags).

Comment: I'll stop, but I don't really get it. How does making sure the right people find the question (keep in mind one of the tags isn't used as much as the other) "serve absolutely no purpose"?

Comment: @youtubefreak You started out the right way - open a topic on Meta asking about an (IMHO perfectly valid) synonym request. What you *shouldn't* do is to wait for less than an hour before starting on an edit spree on your own.

Comment: I get your point about forgetting to improve other aspects, but there may not be anything else to improve.

Comment: @Glorfindlel, yes your're right about that. I haven't really used Meta at all before, I'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: On a related note, does it always take so long for a synonym to be approved?

Comment: @youtubefreak yes, but sometimes a meta post can speed things up.

Comment: @youtubefreak talking of which... I've merged and syn'd the tags

Comment: I think that I'm the (first) one who asked for the merge. Thank you Jon Clements for it btw. The thing about synonym is that we don't always check it, and it has to be done by people with enough rep/contribution in the corresponding tag. And that may happen slowly.

Comment: @Larme your syn. proposal was sitting there without attention from a while back... since proposed syn's aren't exactly obvious (you have to look for them) and some of the tags just don't have enough users to ever approve them, sometimes the only way to do it is as you did and suggest it on meta.